# What's a concise and elegant way to say "this number or zero, whichever is higher"?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to shorten this line of code:

```
const priceSet = price.value > 0 ? price.value : 0;
```

I'm just wondering if there's a cleverer way to write it. It's not important, this isn't a priority, I'm overthinking it, but now I'm just wondering. Is there a way to write this in fewer bytes, or without the ternary?

Comment: Fewer bytes... Do you run your code through a minification process? It will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```
const priceSet = Math.max(price.value, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to be "**clever**" & "**without the ternary**":

  ```
  priceSet = (price.value + Math.abs(price.value)) / 2;
  ```
- If you want "**minimum bytes**" & "**without the ternary**", check @sunknudsen answer.

Answer (score 0):

shorter:

```
let price ={value: 10 }
let price2 ={value: undefined }

const priceSet = price.value || 0; // 10
const priceSet2 = price2.value || 0; // 0
```

Comment: what about negative value !